# regex: Match mutiple ids but not identical

Tags: regex, perl

I have the file which would have the entry as

33745 Neeraj Kumar 33743: License Web Services 33743 WADL generation issues

I want to use regex in such a way that it should not match the same id twice i.e it can match multiples but not identicals
IN above case it should say the count of 33745 as 1 and 33743 as 1

My current code results as count of 33745 as 1 and 33743 as 2

```
foreach $line (@file_list) {

        while ($line =~ m/(\d{4,}[,|:])/g ){
        @temp = split(/[:|,]/, $1);
        push @work_items, $temp[0];
                                        }
                                }

my %count;
map { $count{$_}++ } @work_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unique Matches: Back-Reference in Negative Lookahead**

To retrieve all unique ids, this is enough:

```
@result = $subject =~ m/(\d+)(?!.*\1)/g;
```

**Explanation**

- The parentheses in `(\d+)` capture the id to Group 1
- The negative lookehead `(?!.*\1)` asserts that it is not possible to match any chars, then the id captured by Group 1

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Let me know if this is working or you need tweaks. :)

Comment: I have line in file as :(----) Manish Garg <MG00127052@TechMahindra.com> 74163: V2.0.1_I3_SIT: KeyStroke Logger decrypted file for key stroke displayed a difference of 4 hours from CCM time. - 74163: KeyStroke Logger decrypted file for key stroke displayed a difference of 4 hours from CCM time. 2014/07/04
This gives the output as :updated_workitem value> "74163"
Count> "2"
I want the value of count as 1 as looking for unique occurance of the id:

Comment: In [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/7) you can see that each unique number is matched. But the regex doesn't know "What is an ID", if you want to make it more specific let me know what makes it special.